# Как задать плавное отображение spinner в ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

Использую react + redux, делаю запрос на сервер и пока жду ответа от сервера компонент не отображается, значение `isFetching = false`. Как только ответ получен значение `isFetching = ture`

```
 if (this.props.tv.isFetching) {
    return (<div>hello world</div>)
} else {
    return <Spinner/>;
}
```

В момент когда ждем ответа от сервера хотелось бы отображать спиннер с fade in отображением и fade out уходом.

Пришел к выходу использовать react-transition-group.
Но дилемма в том что не срабатывает не enter не exit, только appear.

```
class Spinner extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <CSSTransition
                classNames={{
                    appear: 'my-appear',
                    appearActive: 'my-active-appear',
                    enter: 'my-enter',
                    enterActive: 'my-active-enter',
                    exit: 'my-exit',
                    exitActive: 'my-active-exit',
                }}
                timeout={{
                    enter: 300,
                    exit: 50550,
                }}
                in
                appear
            >
                <div className="spinner-wrap" >
                    <div className="spinner"/>
                </div>
            </CSSTransition>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`react-transition-group` можно использовать, но, как мне кажется, он избыточен для вашей задачи. Попробуйте вместо того, чтобы монтировать/отмонтировать ваш спиннер в зависимости от `this.props.tv.isFetching` добавлять/удалять ему класс. А в css пропишите стили для плавного удаления и появления.

```
return (
 <div>
    <Spinner hidden={this.props.tv.isFetching}/>
    <div>hello world</div>
 </div>
)
```

Компонент спиннера:

```
class Spinner extends Component {
    render() {
        const { hidden } = this.props
        return (
            <div className={"spinner-wrap hidden_" + hidden} >
                <div className="spinner"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Ну и стили:

```
.spinner-wrap{
  position:fixed;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  left: 0vw;
  transition: left 0.3s;

  &.hidden_true{
    left: -100vw;
  }
}
```

Comment: Плавного ухода не будет, т.к при изменении isFetching на ture будет мгновенно отображаться <div>hello world</div>

Comment: будет, если сразу примонтировать спиннер и хелловорлд, а в зависимости от пропсы менять класс у спиннера.

Comment: при этом оба этих компаненте остаются примонтированными постоянно, но отображение спиннера зависит от пропсов, которые в него передаются от родителя

Comment: Если отображать все это в одном return вместе с hello world, то да будет работать, но если как сейчас у меня сделано что при значении возвращается либо контент, либо спиннер
Не будет, если добавлять сет таймоут на смену свойства и делать доп свойство которое  задает класс а потом уже менять свойство isFetching, то так же будет работать